# Can I access subscribeToTopic using @nuxtjs/firebase module?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, nuxtjs

I am using @nuxtjs/firebase in a nuxt project. The messaging works, I can send messages from postman via fcm to my website. I can't see any documentation on how I can access the subscribeToTopic.

In my nuxt.config.js I have:

```
[
  '@nuxtjs/firebase',
  {
    config: {
      apiKey: "myapiKey",
      authDomain: "myDomain",
      projectId: "myProjectId",
      storageBucket: "myStorageBucker",
      messagingSenderId: "mySenderId",
      appId: "myAppId",
      measurementId: "myMeasurementId"
    },
    services: {
      auth: {
        persistence: 'local',
        initialize: {
          onAuthStateChangedAction: 'onAuthStateChangedAction',
          subscribeManually: false
        },
        ssr: false
      },
      messaging: {
        createServiceWorker: true,
          fcmPublicVapidKey: 'myVapidKey',
          inject: fs.readFileSync('./serviceWorker.js')
      },
      firestore: true
    }
  }
]
```

serviceWorker.js has:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function (e) {
    const data = e.data.json();
    const options = {
        body: data.notification.body,
        icon: data.notification.icon,
        vibrate: [100, 50, 100],
        data: {
            dateOfArrival: Date.now(),
            primaryKey: '2'
        },
    };
})
```

In async mounted I have:

```
const currentToken = await this.$fire.messaging.getToken()
console.log("token", currentToken)
this.$fire.messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
  console.info('Message received. ', payload)
  this.$toast.success(payload.data.text + "</br>" + payload.data.additionalInfo, { icon: payload.data.icon });
})
this.$fire.messaging.onTokenRefresh(async () => {
  const refreshToken = await this.$fire.messaging.getToken()
  console.log('Token Refreshed', refreshToken)
})
```

This all works as expected.

Apparently I should be able to subscribe to topics, in firebase something like the following can be used:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("all")
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    //Successfully Subscribed to Notification Service
                }else{
                //Subscription  Notification Service failed
                }
            }
```

But, I cannot see how to do that using @nuxtjs/firebase module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no client-side API in the JavaScript SDK to subscribe to a topic. You'll instead need to use a (server-side) Admin SDK to accomplish this.

For example, the `subscribeToTopic` method you refer to exists in the Node.js SDK and in the Java SDK, but not in the JavaScript/Web or Android SDKs.

I recommend studying the documentation on [subscribing a web client to a topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/topic-messaging#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic) a bit further.

Once you subscribe a client to a topic from the server, the existing client-side code you already have should start receiving messages to that topic too.

Comment: Excellent! Got it working now, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.